# Max # azure cloud service instances AFTER customer service call

Tags: azure

I'm reading about a limit on the number of instances I can create for a cloud service and also on the number of procs. When calling customer support, they can increase this limit for you.

My question is if customer support will set it to any limit you want or is there still a limit? I might need at least fifty instances for my roles and if things are going really well, up to 100 or 200 for two hours a day. Would that be a potential problem?? If so I might need to review my entire azure choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit is mostly to do with credit rating. If you can assure MSFT that you are good for the costs you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to everything.  The limit may be high, but at some point there must be a ceiling to any finite resource.  :)

The more important issue here is likely to be the CPU core count, not the number of instances.  This relates to the instance size (small has 1 core, an Extra Large has 8 cores, etc.).  I don't recall the max number of cores that can allotted to a single Cloud Service, but it's likely fairly high (in the hundreds).  200 small instances are probably OK, while 200 XL instances (weighing in at 1600 cores) may be a little more challenging.